# How do I get rid of the "log in to social club" window?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-iv, rockstar-games-social-club

Whenever I launch GTA-IV (via Steam), I'm prompted to "log in to Social Club". I'm not interested in multiplayer or video uploading features, at least at the moment; how can I stop this window from appearing every time I try to launch the game?

Comment: Good question. I don't think you can (haven't found a solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to get rid of that screen via steam. Game will check if you have a working net connection, everytime it starts via steam. So, it will ask for you to log in to social club everytime. If you start game, without an internet connection, it should not ask for the same.

Comment: to run a steam game without internet connection, you have to switch to steam's offline mode _while_ connected to the internet (and after having run the game at least once online)

Comment: @Tobias - so you have to deal with it once instead of indefinitely. If it works, It's still better than the alternative (of not changing anything at all).

Comment: @Raven though I think the social club login also has a `remember me` option

Comment: This for me is not an acceptable answer, as a paying customer, the computer owner, etc.

Answer (score 6):

This is obvious 4+ years old now but here's the answer, which I found after fiddling around intercepting windows messages.

Rename: `<steam path>\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto IV\GTAIV\paul.dll`

to: `<steam path>\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto IV\GTAIV\paul.disable.dll`

Annoying Rockstar Social Club dialog will now be suppressed.

Also, if you have more VRAM than 2GB then GTA 4 thinks you don't meet minimum requirements and locks the game to 800x600 with the lowest available graphics settings. To fix this click the `SET LAUNCH OPTIONS` button in the game's steam properties sheet and add `-norestrictions -nomemrestrict`

Comment: This worked for me in 2019!